# Why Isn't CodeIgniter Recognizing the Controllers When Using the Wpbridge Library?

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

Using the [Wpbridge library](http://www.alternativez.info/codeigniter-wordpress-bridging-library/) I'm able to login from the Wordpress interface into the initial page of a previously created CI site, with all the same functionality and css, but it only allows me to access the landing page with the root of the site:

localhost/bizdoc_online/corporationdocs/

If I try to access the landing page with the full path to the controller:

localhost/bizdoc_online/corporationdocs/user/login

it gets the standard CI 404 error page. I've created a practice CI site from scratch to see what happens and it logged into the landing page with the controller in the url and allowed me to go from page to page and logout without any errors.

This means that it would have to be something in the previously existent CI site that is preventing the controllers from being found. Can anyone explain why it would only allow me into the landing page with the root url for the CI site and not recognize any of the controllers or methods within the controllers? Is there a way to make CI find the controllers and methods after using Wpbridge to login from Wordpress?

Comment: `localhost/bizdoc_online/corporationdocs/index.php/user/login` try this and see

Comment: The site is configured not to use index.php. It works perfectly fine without it when it's not being accessed through the wordpress login. I think it's about the controllers not being found when it's being accessed through the Wpbridge class and I want to figure out how to reestablish access to the controllers.

Comment: I tried using the index.php file like you said and it displayed the url without getting a 404 error. I set the redirect to display with the index.php, but instead of getting the 404 error it displayed the url and showed the original landing page without the additional stuff I added into it. I'm going to look further into this tomorrow. I put index.php into $config['index_page'] and it did the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direcition Abdulla. I'm pretty sure that the landing page being refreshed is about the CI security not being integrated with the wordpress login system yet. When I used a wordpress logout in a controller without trying to access the inner part of the site it recognized the control and the function and logged me out. It didn't occur to me that the index.php would be expected when it wasn't declared in $config['index_page'], but I guess the Wpbridge class expects the urls to have the index.php in them. Thanks.